# Get zeros with car plates

Tags: python, haskell

When I was little, I played the next game with my cousins:

"Zero in the car's license plates": by using the numbers in the car's license plate numbers and using the elementary operations (sum, subtraction, product and division) once each, you had to find an order that equaled 0.

For example, if we have the following license plate:

`2591 -->  (2*5)-(9+1) = 0`

`2491 -->  (2*4)+1 -9  = 0`

I would like to make a program in Haskell or Python that it is able to play this game, and print the steps that gives a result of 0.

```
getZero 2491 =  2*4+1-9
getZero 2591 =  2*5-9+1
```

Maybe its impossible to make this; I hope that you can help me.

Comment: Do the numbers need to remain ordered?

Comment: Well, it shouldn't be too hard as the order of the numbers matters. You'll just have to split out the numbers, then run them through each possible combination of possible equations and see if any of them equal 0

Comment: It doesn't matter @Alex

Answer (score 1):

This is probably off topic but a fun toy puzzle.

An easy way to think of the issue is in perhaps four separate parts:

1. Boring plumbing for the arguments and printing the results
2. Construct all possible expressions of binary operations of the given numbers.
3. Interpret these expressions to obtain a numeric literal and drop any result that is not zero.
4. Pretty print the expression.

We could perform extra steps, such as filtering out duplicates based on algebraic rules (`a + b` and `b + a` are morally the same), but I skipped that.

**The boring plumbing** is just getting our plate numbers (one for each argument), breaking those down into digits, running our computation, and printing the solution.

```hs
import Data.Foldable
import Data.List
import System.Environment

main :: IO ()
main =
  do ns <- getArgs
     for_ ns $ \n -> do
        let digitList = map (read . (:[])) (n :: String) :: [Int]
        putStrLn $ "---------- " ++ show n ++ " ----------"
        putStrLn $ unlines (map render (solutions digitList))
```

**Construction** The real fun is in this construction of a binary tree of operations and leafs with the literals.  First we define our expression language:

```hs
data Expr = Add Expr Expr
          | Sub Expr Expr
          | Mul Expr Expr
          | Div Expr Expr
          | Lit Int
        deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

And we can use these expressions along with a Haskell list monad to build all possible expressions (assuming a non-empty list as input):

```hs
operations :: [Expr -> Expr -> Expr]
operations = [Add, Sub, Mul, Div]

exprsOf :: [Expr] -> [Expr]
exprsOf [term] = [term]
exprsOf xs =
  do x <- xs
     y <- (delete x xs)
     o <- operations
     exprsOf (o x y : delete y (delete x xs))
```

That is, `x` is one of the elements in the original set of expressions.  `y` is another element (but not x).  `o` is one of our legal operations (addition, subtraction, etc).  And we recursively reduce this list size till we are left with the top level expression (variable name `term`).  If you don't understand the operation that's OK - specific parts that confuse you would make a fine (on topic) question.

**Interpretation** With the expressions built we can now interpret them and filter out any that don't result in zero.

The interpreter is just using addition (`+`) when we see our `Add` constructor and same for the other operations.  I lifted everything into the Maybe Applicative because I didn't want division by zero or with a remainder to show up in our results.

```hs
interp :: Expr -> Maybe Int
interp (Lit n) = Just n
interp (Add a b) = (+) <$> interp a <*> interp b
interp (Sub a b) = (-) <$> interp a <*> interp b
interp (Mul a b) = (*) <$> interp a <*> interp b
interp (Div a b) | interp b == Just 0 = Nothing
                 | interp b == Nothing = Nothing
                 | otherwise          =
        case divMod <$> interp a <*> interp b of
            Nothing -> Nothing
            Just (x,0) -> Just x
            _ -> Nothing -- Ignore uneven division
```

Applying this interpretation is just a matter of filtering for `Just 0`:

```
solutions :: [Int] -> [Expr]
solutions xs = filter ((== Just 0) . interp) $ exprsOf (map Lit xs)
```

**Rendering** Finally, there's a pretty ugly render function just to emit the proper parenthesis so we see the right order of operations:

```hs
render :: Expr -> String
render (Lit n) = show n
render (Add a b) = "(" ++ render a ++ " + " ++ render b ++ ")"
render (Sub a b) = "(" ++ render a ++ " - " ++ render b ++ ")"
render (Mul a b) = "(" ++ render a ++ " * " ++ render b ++ ")"
render (Div a b) = "(" ++ render a ++ " / " ++ render b ++ ")"
```

**Example Run**

```hs
*Main> :main 2591
---------- "2591" ----------
(((2 * 5) - 9) - 1)
(1 - ((2 * 5) - 9))
(((2 * 5) - 1) - 9)
(9 - ((2 * 5) - 1))
((9 - (2 * 5)) + 1)
(1 + (9 - (2 * 5)))
((9 + 1) - (2 * 5))
((2 * 5) - (9 + 1))
((1 - (2 * 5)) + 9)
(9 + (1 - (2 * 5)))
((1 + 9) - (2 * 5))
((2 * 5) - (1 + 9))
(((5 * 2) - 9) - 1)
(1 - ((5 * 2) - 9))
(((5 * 2) - 1) - 9)
(9 - ((5 * 2) - 1))
((9 - (5 * 2)) + 1)
(1 + (9 - (5 * 2)))
((9 + 1) - (5 * 2))
((5 * 2) - (9 + 1))
((1 - (5 * 2)) + 9)
(9 + (1 - (5 * 2)))
((1 + 9) - (5 * 2))
((5 * 2) - (1 + 9))
(((9 + 1) / 2) - 5)
(5 - ((9 + 1) / 2))
(((9 + 1) / 5) - 2)
(2 - ((9 + 1) / 5))
((2 * 5) - (9 + 1))
((9 + 1) - (2 * 5))
((5 * 2) - (9 + 1))
((9 + 1) - (5 * 2))
(((1 + 9) / 2) - 5)
(5 - ((1 + 9) / 2))
(((1 + 9) / 5) - 2)
(2 - ((1 + 9) / 5))
((2 * 5) - (1 + 9))
((1 + 9) - (2 * 5))
((5 * 2) - (1 + 9))
((1 + 9) - (5 * 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the best implementation, because there are quite a lot of repeats, but does get a result.

Using [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html), I generated every different state (permutation) that the numbers and operations could be in, e.g.:

`[('1', '2', '3', '4'), ('1', '2', '4', '3'), ('1', '3', '2', '4'), ('1', '3', '4', '2'), ('1', '4', '2', '3'),  ....... ('4', '1', '3', '2'), ('4', '2', '1', '3'), ('4', '2', '3', '1'), ('4', '3', '1', '2'), ('4', '3', '2', '1')]`

`[('+', '-', '*'), ('+', '*', '-') ......  ('/', '-', '*'), ('/', '*', '-')]`

...then, I made a function that adds brackets to every possible state of the calculation:

`[1,'+',2,'-',3,'*',4]` becomes:

```
1 + 2 - 3 * 4
( 1 + 2 ) - ( 3 * 4 )
( 1 + 2 - 3 ) * 4
1 + ( 2 - 3 * 4 )
( 1 + 2 ) - 3 * 4
1 + 2 - ( 3 * 4 )
1 + ( 2 - 3 ) * 4
```

... and then, evaluated each different possibility, and if it was zero I printed it out.

Heres all the code:

```
from itertools import permutations, combinations, chain
import sys

operations = ['+', '-', '*', '/'] # basic operations

# add every combination of brackets to the calculation
def addBrackets(calc):
    possibilities = []
    possibilities.append(" ".join(calc))
    possibilities.append(" ".join(str(s) for s in list(chain(["("], calc[:3], [")"], [calc[3]], ["("], calc[4:], [")"]))))
    possibilities.append(" ".join(str(s) for s in list(chain(["("], calc[:-2], [")"], calc[-2:]))))
    possibilities.append(" ".join(str(s) for s in list(chain(calc[:2], ["("], calc[2:], [")"]))))
    possibilities.append(" ".join(str(s) for s in list(chain(["("], calc[:3], [")"], calc[3:]))))
    possibilities.append(" ".join(str(s) for s in list(chain(calc[:4], ["("], calc[4:], [")"]))))
    return possibilities

def getZero(n): # 2491
    nums = [x for x in str(n)] # [2, 4, 9, 1]
    while len(nums) < 4:
        nums = ['0'] + nums # add zeroes if the input was less than 1000 e.g. [5, 3, 1] -> [0, 5, 3, 1]
    possible_number_order = list(permutations(nums)) # get every number order
    possible_op_order = list(combinations(operations, 3)) # get combinations of 3 of the operations
    possible_op_permutations = list(chain(list(permutations(p)) for p in possible_op_order)) # chain together all the permutations of each combination
    possible_op_order = []
    for perms in possible_op_permutations: 
        possible_op_order.extend(perms) # add all the lists into one
    for n in possible_number_order: # for each number order
        for op in possible_op_order: # for each operation order
            calculation = [n[0],op[0],n[1],op[1],n[2],op[2],n[3]] # create a list with the order of the operation
            for calc in addBrackets(calculation): # for each bracket position
                try:
                    result = eval(calc) # evaluate
                    if abs(result) <= 0.001: # to check for float comparison
                        print("{} = {}".format(calc, 0))
                except: # ZeroDivisionError
                    continue

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for user_input in [int(n) for n in sys.argv[1:]]:
        print("-------{0:04}-------".format(user_input)) # print 0 padded output
        getZero(user_input)
```

Enter the input as command line arguments:

```
$ python3.6 zerogame.py 2491 2591
-------2491-------
( 2 * 4 - 9 ) + 1 = 0
( 2 * 4 ) - 9 + 1 = 0
( 2 * 4 ) + ( 1 - 9 ) = 0
( 2 * 4 + 1 ) - 9 = 0
( 2 * 4 ) + 1 - 9 = 0
2 * 4 + ( 1 - 9 ) = 0
2 + ( 1 - 9 ) / 4 = 0
( 4 * 2 - 9 ) + 1 = 0
( 4 * 2 ) - 9 + 1 = 0
( 4 * 2 ) + ( 1 - 9 ) = 0
( 4 * 2 + 1 ) - 9 = 0
( 4 * 2 ) + 1 - 9 = 0
4 * 2 + ( 1 - 9 ) = 0
4 + ( 1 - 9 ) / 2 = 0
9 - ( 2 * 4 + 1 ) = 0
9 - ( 4 * 2 + 1 ) = 0
9 - ( 1 + 2 * 4 ) = 0
9 - ( 1 + 4 * 2 ) = 0
( 1 + 2 * 4 ) - 9 = 0
1 + ( 2 * 4 - 9 ) = 0
1 + ( 2 * 4 ) - 9 = 0
( 1 + 4 * 2 ) - 9 = 0
1 + ( 4 * 2 - 9 ) = 0
1 + ( 4 * 2 ) - 9 = 0
( 1 - 9 ) + ( 2 * 4 ) = 0
( 1 - 9 ) + 2 * 4 = 0
1 - 9 + ( 2 * 4 ) = 0
( 1 - 9 ) / 2 + 4 = 0
( 1 - 9 ) + ( 4 * 2 ) = 0
( 1 - 9 ) + 4 * 2 = 0
1 - 9 + ( 4 * 2 ) = 0
( 1 - 9 ) / 4 + 2 = 0
-------2591-------
( 2 * 5 ) - ( 9 + 1 ) = 0
2 * 5 - ( 9 + 1 ) = 0
( 2 * 5 ) - ( 1 + 9 ) = 0
2 * 5 - ( 1 + 9 ) = 0
2 - ( 9 + 1 ) / 5 = 0
2 - ( 1 + 9 ) / 5 = 0
( 5 * 2 ) - ( 9 + 1 ) = 0
5 * 2 - ( 9 + 1 ) = 0
( 5 * 2 ) - ( 1 + 9 ) = 0
5 * 2 - ( 1 + 9 ) = 0
5 - ( 9 + 1 ) / 2 = 0
5 - ( 1 + 9 ) / 2 = 0
( 9 - 2 * 5 ) + 1 = 0
9 - ( 2 * 5 ) + 1 = 0
( 9 - 5 * 2 ) + 1 = 0
9 - ( 5 * 2 ) + 1 = 0
( 9 + 1 ) - ( 2 * 5 ) = 0
9 + ( 1 - 2 * 5 ) = 0
( 9 + 1 ) - 2 * 5 = 0
9 + 1 - ( 2 * 5 ) = 0
( 9 + 1 ) / 2 - 5 = 0
( 9 + 1 ) - ( 5 * 2 ) = 0
9 + ( 1 - 5 * 2 ) = 0
( 9 + 1 ) - 5 * 2 = 0
9 + 1 - ( 5 * 2 ) = 0
( 9 + 1 ) / 5 - 2 = 0
( 1 - 2 * 5 ) + 9 = 0
1 - ( 2 * 5 ) + 9 = 0
( 1 - 5 * 2 ) + 9 = 0
1 - ( 5 * 2 ) + 9 = 0
( 1 + 9 ) - ( 2 * 5 ) = 0
1 + ( 9 - 2 * 5 ) = 0
( 1 + 9 ) - 2 * 5 = 0
1 + 9 - ( 2 * 5 ) = 0
( 1 + 9 ) / 2 - 5 = 0
( 1 + 9 ) - ( 5 * 2 ) = 0
1 + ( 9 - 5 * 2 ) = 0
( 1 + 9 ) - 5 * 2 = 0
1 + 9 - ( 5 * 2 ) = 0
( 1 + 9 ) / 5 - 2 = 0
```